# Arduino Infinite Looping using Serial.print

Tags: c, loops, printing, arduino, arduino-uno

This program is supposed to detect user input in serial monitor, then outputs the same content but with a period dot at the end of the sentence.

But for some reason my code below prints out infinite dots before I even start typing:

```
char incoming;

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(9600); // Select baud
}

void loop() {
  
  if (Serial.available() > 0){ // Check if serial is empty
      incoming = Serial.read();// Set incoming as the input
      Serial.print(incoming);// Prints input
  }

  if (bool con=true){
      con=false;
      Serial.print(".");
    }
}
```

How do I resolve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `if (bool con=true)` is *always* true. You need to figure out how to detect "the end of the sentence". How will you know from reading the input that the "sentence" is ending?

Comment: Does the Enter key define the end of the sentence? It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a variable inside a if condition is not a good practice, it will always be true/false!
Set a better scope for that variable.
If you want to check user input I would read until '\r' character is received.

Comment: Unless initialized to *false*... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (bool con=true)
```

if this form was permitted (which is not in C) it would be always true and change its value to false has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single dot after a given input. Just do something like this:

```
char incoming;

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(9600); // Select baud
}

void loop() {
  
  if (Serial.available() > 0){ // Check if serial is empty
      incoming = Serial.read();// Set incoming as the input
      Serial.print(incoming + ".");// Prints input with dot

  }
}
```

I think this is what you are wanting as output:

**input**: A sentence
**output**: A sentence.